# How can I find the solutions of this third degree equation?

Tags: polynomials

I can't find the solutions of the following third degree equation:

$$4 \lambda^3 + 4 \lambda^2 - \lambda -1 =0$$

with Ruffini's rule. Can someone help me find $\lambda_{1,2,3}$? Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: If you meant $\;4\lambda^2\;$ in the second term, then clearly $\;\lambda=-1\;$ is a root, so you can then divide the polynomial by $\;\lambda+1\;$ and then work with the resulting quadratic.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Comment: There is only one real root. $\lambda = \frac12 \left((1+\sqrt2)^{1/3}-\frac1{(1+\sqrt2)^{1/3}}\right)$

Comment: @Alizter Unless that number is $\;-1\;$ that is wrong, as $\;-1\;$ is definitely a root.

Comment: @Timbuc When I commented it was asking for $4\lambda^3 + 4\lambda - \lambda - 1 = 0$

Comment: @Timbuc Damn, typo. Sorry, I have fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$4\lambda^3+4\lambda^2-\lambda-1=(\lambda+1)(4\lambda^2-1)$$

Comment: Thank you for your help Timbuc. I forgot to consider $\pm 1$ when looking for the root. Idiotic mistake and question. The eigenvalues are then: $\lambda_1=-1$, $\lambda_2=- \frac{1}{2}$ and $\lambda_3= \frac{1}{2}$.